# MemoryError when creating and writing

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management, numpy, large-files

I'm relatively new at coding and was working in python on taking a large amount (~2.0 GB) of data from an output file and turning it into a readable and sorted list.  My major issue is creating a test file of that size. The input file will be a long array that is something around 2.56*10^8 (row) by 1 (column) The end result is something around a 6.4*10^7 (row) by 4 (column) array and displaying it. To create a sample array, I have been using this code (note that the size is not final, its just as large as I could get it by increasing the size by powers of 2).

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess as subp
from array import array

keepData = 1

if(not keepData):
  subp.call(['rm', 'Bertha.DAT']) #removes previous file if present

girth = int(8e6) #number of final rows

girthier = girth*4
bigger_tim = np.zeros(girthier) #initial array

File = 'Bertha.DAT'
bid = open(File, 'wb')
for ii in range(0,girth):
    tiny_tim = 100*(2*np.random.rand(1,3)-1)
    bigger_tim[ii*4]=4
    bigger_tim[ii*4+1]=tiny_tim[0,0]
    bigger_tim[ii*4+2]=tiny_tim[0,1]
    bigger_tim[ii*4+3]=tiny_tim[0,2]
    #for loop that inputs values in the style of the input result

line.tofile(bid) #writes into file
bid.close()
```

This code works for creating files that are 250MB, but they cannot create any larger than that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I am also adding in my second code to see if there is a problem there as well due to large memory usage.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

girth = int(24e6)

Matrix = np.zeros((girth,4))

Bertha = np.fromfile('Bertha.DAT',dtype = float,count = -1, sep = "")

for jj in range(0,girth):
    Matrix[jj,0] = Bertha[jj*4]
    Matrix[jj,1] = Bertha[jj*4+1]
    Matrix[jj,2] = Bertha[jj*4+2]
    Matrix[jj,3] = Bertha[jj*4+3] 

Table = pd.DataFrame({'Atomic Number':Matrix[:,0], 'X Position':Matrix[:,1], 'Y Position':Matrix[:,2], 'Z Position':Matrix[:,3]})
print Table
```

EDIT: First code runs with up to 24e6 as the "girth" value, but gets the following error with 32e6:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-cb13d37b70b9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3/Big_Bertha.py', wdir='D:/WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3')

   File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:/WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3/Big_Bertha.py", line 19, in <module>
    bigger_tim = np.zeros(girthier) #initial array

MemoryError
```

This looks like I cannot create the initial dummy matrix to store values due to insufficient memory.

The second one has a very similar issue but with a different error at 24e6 as the "girth" value.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-268052dcc4e8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3/binaryReader.py', wdir='D:/WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3')

   File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:/WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3/binaryReader.py", line 14, in <module>
    Bertha = np.fromfile('Bertha.DAT',dtype = float,count = -1, sep = "")

MemoryError
```

Comment: When asking questions about exceptions in Python, please post (the relevant part of) the error trace. It's there for a reason: it shows the exact line in which the program failed, making debugging much easier.

Comment: I apologize, and I have now added the error traces because I don't know what is relevant.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit python? Your data is so big that it may exceed the addressing limits in the 32 bit version.

Comment: I am currently using 32-bit python, but if the addressing limit of the 32-bit version is 2GB as i have seen in multiple places, the variables created do not go over that value according to my calculations for any variable. The final test that I was approaching of 64e6 should be just under that value.

Comment: There is an excellent library [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) which allows you to do large file handling painlessly. With it you can write e.g. also blocks etc. to your final matrix without keeping or creating needless copies in memory. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you receive comes from the fact that python cannot allocate any more memory.

In your second example you are allocating a numpy table with 32 million rows and 4 columns. With the usual double precision floats this alone is 1 GiB. The row `np.fromfile =` needs to load a very big file, as the file length should match `Matrix`, i.e. you will need to have at least 1 GiB of data from the file.

And there it is: 1 GiB + 1 GiB = 2 GiB, which is the maximum for 32-bit python. (And that is why 24 million rows is ok.) That is why the error is thrown when the data is loaded from the file. Also, the limit is not 2 GiB for user's data, it is 2 GiB in total, which may be much less in practice.

There are several things you can do:

1. Do not create the empty table. Load the data from the file and reshape it to the shape you want (four columns and as many rows as it takes):

   `m = np.fromfile("Bertha.DAT").reshape(-1,4)`
2. Use something else as the data type than float (which is an 8-bit double). If you do not run into precision trouble, use 'float32' (or 'f4'). However, you cannot change the data type in `np.fromfile` as there it determines the data type and order in the file, as well.
3. Use 64-bit python. If you deal with large data, that is the way to go. It consumes a bit more memory in some cases (and a lot in some others, but not with numpy), but if your computer has a lot of RAM, even very large tables work very well.

If you are interested in seeing how much your objects occupy memory, the `sys` module has a nice function `sys.getsizeof` for they purpose, e.g. `sys.getsizeof(Bertha)`.

---

There are a few stylistic things in your code which you might want to fix. One is about naming your variables, they should be in lower case (class names are capitalised). For this type of information it is very useful to read through the `PEP 8` recommendation. (The name `Matrix` is a bit unfortunate in any case, as there is something called `numpy.matrix`.)

Another thing that catches my eye is that you are iterating through a numpy array with a for loop. That is usually a warning sign of something done in a very slow way. There are rare cases where you need to do that, but usually there are very concise and fast ways to manipulate the arrays.

Comment: This worked for me. The reshape command was something I overlooked and the upgrade to 64-bit allowed for the creation of larger files. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you are trying to keep everything in memory when the most you ever need to keep in memory is four lines of data. This quick and dirty code does the job using no more memory than a just loaded Python 2.7 interpreter.

```
#!python2

import sqlite3

def make_narrow_file(rows, path):
    """make a text data file in path with rows of elements"""
    with open(path, 'w') as outf:
        for i in xrange(rows):
            outf.write(hex(i) + '\n')

def widen_file(inpath, outpath):
    """tranforms the single column in inpath to four columns in outpath"""
    inf = open(inpath)
    compose = []
    with open(outpath, 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            compose.append(line.rstrip())
            if len(compose) == 4:
                outf.write(' '.join(compose))
                outf.write('\n')
                compose = []
    inf.close()

# But flat files are an inconvenient way for dealing with massive data.
# Put another way, flat ascii files are degenerate databases, so we'll use
# the sqlite database which is built into Python.

def create_database(db_path):
    """creates a database schema to hold 4 strings per row"""
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('drop table if exists wide')
    c.execute('create table wide (a, b, c, d)')
    conn.close()

def fill_database(inpath, db_path):
    """tranforms the single column of data in inpath to four columns in 
       db_path"""
    inf = open(inpath)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path, isolation_level='DEFERRED')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    compose = []
    for line in inf:
        compose.append(line.rstrip())
        if len(compose) == 4:
            cur.execute('insert into wide values(?, ?, ?, ?)', compose)
            compose = []
    conn.commit()
    inf.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_narrow_file(int(2e8), 'bertha.dat')
    widen_file('bertha.dat', 'berthaw.dat')

    create_database('berthaw.db')
    fill_database('bertha.dat', 'berthaw.db')
```

Comment: If he is using the data for numerical calculations, using a sqlite database is not imho a good way to go. He should use [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) with the hdf5 format.

Comment: You are more than welcome to write your own answer, especially because the OP didn't specify intentions. I also doubt your claim that pytables is superior for simple columnar data.